# Can you sync a local view to a remote Azure table?

Tags: sql-server, azure

Here is my scenario, we have some data we want to sync from a local database to an Azure database. The local table has (for example) 20 columns. The Azure database is a subset of this data, with only 10 columns.

Is it possible to create a local view to match the schema of the Azure table, and then sync the data in the local view to the remote Azure table?

Comment: You can probably use ADF (by copying data or CDC such as auto incremental extraction in mapping data flow or native CDC) or sql server replication. For this CDC should be the best option, but I am not sure if you can CDC from the views.

Comment: Why not just use a linked server and have your view query against it?

Answer (score 0):

As @Sean Lange said, you can use the linked server option to sync data between a local view and an Azure SQL table. To create a linked server, follow these steps:

1. On your on-premises server, go to the server object, right-click on Linked Server, and select New Linked Server as shown below:

[image]

2. Provide the Azure SQL server name and database in the General section of the linked server, as shown below:

[image]

3. Go to the Security tab and select `Be made using the security context`. Provide the username and password for the Azure SQL server, as shown below:

[image]

4. Click OK. If all information is correct, the linked server will be tested and created successfully, as shown below:

[image]

You can sync data between the local view and the Azure SQL table using the linked server. For example, if you have a local view named `SampleView` as shown below:

[image]

And a table named `SampTable` in the Azure SQL table, as shown below:

[image]

You can sync only the remaining rows from the local view to the Azure SQL table using the linked server with the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM <view>
INSERT INTO [<linkedServer>].[<database>].[<schema>].[<table>] (<columns>)
SELECT <columns> FROM <view>
WHERE (condition);
```

The code will run successfully, as shown below:

[image]

And the Azure SQL table will be updated, as shown below:

[image]